# Come back hard on us

Tags: idioms, american-english, vocabulary

I want to convey to a client that if they don't take things seriously and provide incorrect information then our management will come back very hard on us.is this the right sentence or any idiom or vocabulary i can use in business english context

Comment: Could you please provide a little more context to clarify the question? It sounds a little like _repercussions_.

Comment: The more common idiom for the context is *our management will **crack down hard** on us [if we fail to ensure that our clients are taking matters sufficiently seriously]*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the idiom you're looking for is "come *down* very hard on us," [defined](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/come%20down%20hard%20%28on%29) as:

> to express one's unfavorable opinion of the worth or quality of

You could also say that it will "come back to bite us"—in order words, it will cause problems later.

Comment: Both idioms would fit, but personally I wouldn't use the second one in business English and even the first might be a bit informal for some contexts ("business english context" covers a wide range of businesses though, so if you're in something casual or informal it might be fine).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looking for an idiom, be specific about what the consequences are. To my ear, "come back hard on us" sounds like a veiled threat of some form of potentially illegal reprisal. Also, "us" is unclear - is it only the team of workers involved on your side, or does "us" include the client. If the consequences are entirely to your team, are you trying to make an appeal to the client's sense of fairness? It might be more effective to persuade them based on how their own concerns will be impacted by incorrect information rather than how your team will be impacted.

Comment: This sounds a little like a comment _looking for clarification_...